# Pandas - Finding the means of sections of rows

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I am a newbie to pandas and I came across a dataset that contains the unemployment rate of Kings County seasonally starting from 1990 up to 2017. Currently the dataframe looks like this: 
[Image of my current dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSjto.jpg)

Although not shown, the list goes all the way to 1990. 
What can I do to find combine the all the months of each year to find the mean unemployment rate for each year?

I apologize for the poor question format Would there be a code that will output the Area, Year, and the Unemployment Rate together? Thank you

Comment: I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

if your dataframe is called `df`:

```
# Make a new column with unemployment rate as a float, rather than a formatted string with % symbol
df['Unemployment Rate float'] = df['Unemployed'] / df['Labor Force']

# Group by year, and get the mean of the "unemployment rate float" column
df.groupby('Year').mean()['Unemployment Rate Float']
```

Might I suggest the [`pandas` tour](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)?

Comment: Hello @sacul, thank you for your reply. I apologize for the poor question format.  I do have one question, though. Would there be a code that will output the Area, Year, and the Unemployment Rate together? Thank you

Comment: I thought that it was all King's county, but if not, just replace `df.groupby('Year')` with `df.groupby(['Year', 'Area'])`. Then, the index of your resulting `Series` will be `Area` and `Year`